# Calculating a vector gradient

Tags: real-analysis

When I'm learning convex optimization (Borwein and Lewis's book), I encounter a problem which requires me to calculate **gradient** of function $$f(x)=\log\left(\sum_{i=0}^m\exp\langle a_i,x\rangle\right),$$
Note that, here $x$ is a **vector** of an abstruct Euclidean space **E**, and $a_i$'s are arbitrarily given elements(vectors) of **E**. "$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$" is the inner product.
I only know that the gradient of a multivariable function is given by calculating the partial derivative. However, I do not know how to do the calculation when encoountering a complicated vector or matrix, can anyone help me about that?

Comment: Just use the chain rule.  Does it help to know that $\nabla\langle a_i,x\rangle=a_i$?

Comment: I'd be rather thankful if you can give more precise illustration :)

Comment: $$\frac{1}{\sum_{i=0}^m\exp\langle a_i,x\rangle}\sum_{i=0}^m\exp\langle a_i,x\rangle a_i$$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!